# Laravel Blade @include inside foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am trying to include files on my page whose paths are stored in my db. I have tried :-

```
 @foreach($data as $articles)
    @include( $articles->path )
    <br />
 @endforeach
```

This is not working. What am I doing wrong.

I have my files in a folder called pages in view and I have added .blade.php extension as well.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What does your "$articles->path" look like?

Comment: @intelis - View ['pages/articles/first-post'] not found

Comment: @MrShinny - I have stored the path in db as - 'pages/articles/first-post'

Comment: Blade will generate PHP code. Open your view source code and see if the PHP is correct.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro - the php is correct - the page gets displayed when i give the path directly. Only while using blade syntax I am having the problem.

Comment: Error is that the path was not found

Comment: Could you, please, post your path tree?

Comment: What if your try pages.articles.first-post ?

Comment: If the error is that path was not found there is only one explanation. There is no view at application/views/pages/articles/first-post Simple as that

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the path you are referencing actually exists as a file in the views folder i.e.

```
application/views/pages/articles/first-post.blade.php
```

One thing I've seen a lot of people do is add views to the home folder but not added it to the include path e.g.

```
application/views/home/pages/articles/first-post.blade.php
```

Also, it looks like you are not calling the path correctly in @include. Should be using dot notation

```
@include('pages.articles.first-post);
```

You also need to make sure you aren't trying to get a view from a bundle. You need to append the bundle name if you are, like so.

```
@include('bundle_name::pages.articles.first-post');
```

Comment: You don't need to replace slashes by yourself. Laravel will handle them just fine.

Comment: @Gaz_Edge - I tried with dots and with / directly - both r working fine, my question is how to put that in for loop as th e paths r stored in the mysql db @include{ $articles->path} gives error that file not found. If the file wasn't ther then I guess it should not work with dots and / as well rite..?

Comment: you're question is starting to make almost no sense. What is the output of  $articles->path? Its sounds like that is wrong to me